# Segmentation error while using stacks in c++ stl?

Tags: c++

I was trying to write this code for converting infix expression to postfix expression but I'm getting a segmentation fault for some values. Code is :

```
    #include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;
 int prec(char ch){
     if(ch=='^')
         return 3;
     else if(ch=='*' || ch=='/')
         return 2;
     else if(ch=='+' || ch=='-')
         return 1;
     else 
         return 0;
 }

int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
    stack <char> st;
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    for(int i=0;i<21;i++){
        if((s[i]>='a' && s[i]<='z') || (s[i]>='A' && s[i]<='Z'))
            cout<<s[i];
        else{
            if( st.empty())
                st.push(s[i]);
           else  if( s[i]=='(' || prec (s[i])> prec(st.top()))
               st.push(s[i]);
            else if( s[i]==')'){
                while(st.top()!='(')
                {cout<<st.top(); st.pop();}
                st.pop();
            }
            else{
                while(prec(st.top())>=prec(s[i]))
                {
                    cout<<st.top(); st.pop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For smaller expressions, it gives an answer but for an expression like a+b*(c^d-e)^(f+g*h)-i it gives segmentation fault.

Comment: Iterating fixed 21 times regardless of the length of string looks a bad idea.

Comment: Why not using `for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)` in order to avoid that?

Comment: Thou shalt not `top` or `pop` an empty `std::stack`. And under no circumstances should you [hop on pop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hop_on_Pop).

Comment: What did the debugger tell you?

Comment: `s[i]>='a' && s[i]<='z'` -> `std::islower(s[i])` and so on. Don't give up portability for no reason. Or do the whole lot in one go with `std::isalpha`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the iteration should be just in the strings.

This means that

```
for(int i=0;i<21;i++){
```

should be

```
for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){
```

Secondly, you forgot to check if the stack is empty in the loop.

This means that

```
while(prec(st.top())>=prec(s[i]))
```

should be

```
while(!st.empty() && prec(st.top())>=prec(s[i]))
```